# error C2582: 'operator =' function is unavailable in

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I have a class,

```
class Points
{
 public:
 Points();
}
```

and another,

```
class OtherPoints : public Points
{
 public:
 OtherPoints ();

 Points myPoints;
}
```

Now in `OtherPoints()` constructor I am trying to create a `Point` variable like,

```
OtherPoints::OtherPoints(){ 
    myPoints=Points();
}
```

and get the error,

> error C2582: 'operator =' function is unavailable in 'Points'

Comment: Default assignment operator should be available. Is this the complete code ? BTW, you are missing `;` at the end of class definitions.

Comment: Fixing the missing `;` (there are two), [this compiles fine](http://ideone.com/Re94lt). Can post the *real* code? a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) would really help. And FYI, the assignment operation itself is useless. Your `myPoints` is already very-much constructed.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think `myPoints=Points();` is needed;

```
Points myPoints; // This code has already called the constructor (Points();)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I compiled and it's compiling very fine,

```
 #include<iostream>
 using namespace std;
 class points{
    public: points(){cout<<"constructor points called"<<endl;}
            virtual ~points(){cout<<"destructor points called"<<endl;}
 };
 class otherpoints: public points{
                    points x1;
    public: otherpoints(){cout<<"constructor otherpoints called"<<endl;x1=points();}
            ~otherpoints(){cout<<"destructor otherpoints called"<<endl;}
 };
 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
    otherpoints y1=otherpoints();        
    return 0;
 }
```

And the output is,

> constructor points called
>
> constructor points called
>
> constructor otherpoints called
>
> constructor points called
>
> destructor points called
>
> destructor otherpoints called
>
> destructor points called
>
> destructor points called

I didn't get any assignment error.

**Note: Whenever you do inheritence make base class destructor as virtual.**